# Send member function pointer as parameter within another member function

Tags: c++

I want to send a member function as a parameter, but it won't compile. Why doesn't the code work? Here what I have written. If I pass a lambda instead it works though.

```
void global_func(std::function<void(void)>f)
{
    f();
}

class goo
{
public:
    goo() { }

    void func1()
    {
        std::function<void(void)> fp = &goo::func2;  // get a pointer to the function func2 . Error here or next line

        global_func( fp);
    }

    void func2(void)
    {

    }

};


void main()
{
    goo g1;
    g1.func1();

}
```

Here the compiler output ( my program name is tryvector.cpp)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TryVector, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  TryVector.cpp
1>e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(506): error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall goo::* const &)(void),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=void (__thiscall goo::* const &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall goo::* const &)(void),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=void (__thiscall goo::* const &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,goo,,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fret (__thiscall goo::* const )(void),_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,goo,,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fret (__thiscall goo::* const )(void),_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<void,goo,>(_Fret (__thiscall goo::* const )(void))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>          ]
1>          e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<void,goo,>(_Fret (__thiscall goo::* const )(void))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fret=void
1>          ]
1>          d:\vc++ my files\tryvector\tryvector\tryvector.cpp(42) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<void(__thiscall goo::* )(void)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=void (__thiscall goo::* )(void)
1>          ]
1>          d:\vc++ my files\tryvector\tryvector\tryvector.cpp(42) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<void(__thiscall goo::* )(void)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=void (__thiscall goo::* )(void)
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Can you attach the output of the compiler?

Comment: Did you read the error message? It usually tells you what went wrong.

Comment: @user2079303: Not in this case, especially for a beginner.

Comment: @ChristianHackl hence: *usually* :)

Comment: @ark1974: The order of answers depends on votes and is this subject to constant change. And as I said elsewhere, please do NOT change the meaning of a question after you have received several answers. You can instead ask a **new question**, in which you can of course refer to the old one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `std::function<void(void)>` is something which can just be called, without any parameters and without any further context.

`goo:func2`, however, is a non-static member function. It cannot just be called; **it needs a `goo` instance**. It's as if it had an invisible parameter: `void func2(goo* const this)`. And that makes sense, because `func2` probably needs some other non-static `goo` members to do its job.

You have several options:

- Use a lambda to capture `this`, i.e.: `auto const fp = [this] { func2(); };`. Remember, this is equal to `auto const fp = [this] { this->func2(); };`.
- If `func2` doesn't need any non-static members of `goo`, then make the function `static`.
- Use `std::bind`.

Comment: This works too just I put a semicolon after func2() Typos

Comment: Small nitpick, the `func2` isn't defined as `const` so the pointer isn't either. This is also important for the lambda. The `this` must be marked as mutable for non-const member functions.

Comment: @luk32: I don't follow you. That `func2` isn't defined as `const` means that its `this` points to a non-`const` instance of `goo`, but the pointer variable itself is `const`, i.e. `this = something_else;` will not work.

Comment: @ark1974: Please revert your changes and ask a new question, or else future readers will be hopelessly confused...

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oh, yea, I was completely wrong. I misread the position of `const` and I thought that `this` must be marked as mutable because the function is non-const, apparently it doesn't. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

A member function pointer cannot be wrapped into a `std::function<void(void)>` because the member function has an implicit argument: The pointer `this`. But the function wrapper you have defined only takes nullary callables.

Solution 1: Change the function wrapper to `std::function<void(goo*)>`. This will require you to modify `global_func` as well to pass the argument.

Solution 2: Use `std::bind` to generate a functor where the implicit pointer is bound to some instance.

Comment: I think your first sentences should say "cannot".

Comment: @ChristianHackl I broke the sentence while editing. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the member function does not have a matching signature. It also contains implicit `this`. You can make your example by binding the member function and `this`:

```
#include <functional>

void global_func(std::function<void(void)>f)
{
    f();
}

class goo
{
public:
    goo() { }
    void func1()
    {
        std::function<void(void)> fp = std::bind(&goo::func2, this);
        global_func( fp);
    }

    void func2(void) { }
};

int main()
{
    goo g1;
    g1.func1();
}
```

Lambda works, because it can capture `this`.

Static function also would work, because it doesn't have implicit `this` parameter.

Basically you need an instance on which behalf you call the functions, so in your case `this` seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Member functions have an implicit `this` parameter as their first parameter.

```
goo::func2(void)
```

is actually

```
goo::func2(goo* const this);
```

You can do one of two things:

Change the signature of `global_func` to accept a type of `std::function<void(goo*)>`

Use `std::bind` to bind the `this` parameter.

```
std::function<void(void)> fp = std::bind(&goo::func2, this);
global_func(fp);
```

Comment: More precisely, `goo::func2(goo* const this);` for non-const member functions and `goo::func2(goo const* const this);` for const member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your need either to make `func2` a static class member function, or bind it to `this` when you convert it to a `std::function`:

```
 std::function<void()> fp = std::bind(&goo::func2, this);
```

---

Some more -- There are a few other unusual constructs in your code. Although they work, but they are not good C++ practice:

> `void func2(void)`

this is C Style, in C++ you just write `void func2()`. Also:

```
void global_func(std::function<void()>f) // <-- not void(void)
```

Finally, `int main()` not `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

Because a non static member function is not a function. In common implementations, it includes a hidden pointer to the object on which it acts (`this`).

Only static methods can be used the same as functions.